# Import Error for boost.python module created for PCL c++ code

Tags: c++, boost-python, point-cloud-library

I am trying to generate a python wrapper for c++ code which estimates normals of the point cloud using Point Cloud Library(PCL). At this end I am using boost.python . I am able to generate shared library without any trouble but when I try to import it in ipython I get import error

`undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv`

Following is the detailed description of my problem.

First I tried the hello world example from the boost_python documentation.

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

int square(int number)
{
  return number*number;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libhello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
    def("square",square);
}
```

I compile the above code using CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.2)
IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "DEBUG")
  #SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELEASE")
  #SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELWITHDEBINFO")
  #SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "MINSIZEREL")
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0)
IF(Boost_FOUND)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}" "/usr/include/python2.7")
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
  SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS python)

  ADD_LIBRARY(hello SHARED hello.cpp)
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
ELSEIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find correct Boost version. Did you set BOOST_ROOT?")
ENDIF()

IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS("-Wall")
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "CMakeLists.txt has not been tested/written for your compiler.")
ENDIF()
```

This works without any trouble at all.
The ldd outbut for the generated shared library looks as follows:

```
badami@Zusi:~/Codes/indor_seg/pySegment/libC++/build_hello$ ldd libhello.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff04695000)
    libboost_python-py27.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f4d0c234000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4d0bf30000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4d0bd1a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4d0b955000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4d0b64f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4d0c68e000)
```

I can import this library in ipython environment and call the defined methods without any trouble.

So now, I try to repeat this example for my normal estimation code using PCL for the following code.

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/features/integral_image_normal.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

int normalEstimation()
{
    // load point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd", *cloud);

    // estimate normals
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

    pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    ne.setNormalEstimationMethod (ne.AVERAGE_3D_GRADIENT);
    ne.setMaxDepthChangeFactor(0.02f);
    ne.setNormalSmoothingSize(10.0f);
    ne.setInputCloud(cloud);
    ne.compute(*normals);

    // visualize normals
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("PCL Viewer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    viewer.addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZ,pcl::Normal>(cloud, normals);

    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
      viewer.spinOnce ();
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libpcltest)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("normalEstimation", normalEstimation);
}
```

Using the CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.2)
IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "DEBUG")
  #SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELEASE")
  #SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELWITHDEBINFO")
  #SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "MINSIZEREL")
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0)
IF(Boost_FOUND)

  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}" "/usr/include/python2.7")
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
  SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS python)

  FIND_PACKAGE(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization features)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${PYTHON_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  ADD_LIBRARY(pcltest SHARED normal_estimation.cpp)
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(pcltest ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
ELSEIF(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find correct Boost version. Did you set BOOST_ROOT?")
ENDIF()

IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS("-Wall")
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "CMakeLists.txt has not been tested/written for your compiler.")
ENDIF()
```

The ldd output for the generated shared library is as below:

```
badami@Zusi:~/Codes/indor_seg/pySegment/libC++/build$ ldd libpcltest.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe05793000)
    libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f29d38a4000)
    libpcl_common.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_common.so.1.7 (0x00007f29d35f0000)
    libpcl_io.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.7 (0x00007f29d3138000)
    libpcl_search.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_search.so.1.7 (0x00007f29d2d8d000)
    libpcl_visualization.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.7 (0x00007f29d2a36000)
    libpcl_features.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_features.so.1.7 (0x00007f29d0f38000)
    libvtkRendering.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkRendering.so.5.8 (0x00007f29d0832000)
    libvtkFiltering.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkFiltering.so.5.8 (0x00007f29d02a9000)
    libvtkCommon.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkCommon.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cfd33000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f29cfa2f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f29cf729000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f29cf513000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f29cf14e000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f29cef38000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f29ced1a000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f29ceb0b000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f29ce8f5000)
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f29ce6dc000)
    libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f29ce4d5000)
    libpcl_io_ply.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_io_ply.so.1.7 (0x00007f29ce286000)
    libvtkImaging.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkImaging.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cdc99000)
    libvtkIO.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cd518000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f29cd2f2000)
    libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f29cd0db000)
    libOpenNI2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so.0 (0x00007f29cce80000)
    libOpenNI.so.0 => /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0 (0x00007f29ccc08000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f29d3d22000)
    libpcl_octree.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_octree.so.1.7 (0x00007f29cc81b000)
    libpcl_kdtree.so.1.7 => /usr/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so.1.7 (0x00007f29cc4f4000)
    libvtkGraphics.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkGraphics.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cbb38000)
    libvtkHybrid.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkHybrid.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cb656000)
    libvtkWidgets.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkWidgets.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cb282000)
    libvtkCharts.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkCharts.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cafa4000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f29cad15000)
    libvtkftgl.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkftgl.so.5.8 (0x00007f29cab0a000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f29c9e57000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f29c9972000)
    libgl2ps.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgl2ps.so.0 (0x00007f29c975f000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f29c94f9000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f29c91c4000)
    libvtksys.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtksys.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c8f88000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f29c8ce5000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f29c8add000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f29c88c4000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f29c86b4000)
    libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f29c8485000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f29c7f4d000)
    libvtkDICOMParser.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkDICOMParser.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c7d34000)
    libnetcdf.so.7 => /usr/lib/libnetcdf.so.7 (0x00007f29c79f7000)
    libnetcdf_c++.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnetcdf_c++.so.4 (0x00007f29c77da000)
    libvtkmetaio.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkmetaio.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c754d000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f29c7294000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f29c703f000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f29c6dcd000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f29c6ba3000)
    libavformat.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.54 (0x00007f29c6881000)
    libavcodec.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.54 (0x00007f29c5b2d000)
    libavutil.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.52 (0x00007f29c5908000)
    libswscale.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.2 (0x00007f29c56c1000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f29c54b0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f29c52ac000)
    libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 (0x00007f29c5097000)
    libvtkverdict.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkverdict.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c4e61000)
    libvtkParallel.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkParallel.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c4a5e000)
    libvtkexoIIc.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkexoIIc.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c4814000)
    libvtkViews.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkViews.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c457a000)
    libvtkInfovis.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkInfovis.so.5.8 (0x00007f29c40e2000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f29c3eb4000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f29c3ca2000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f29c3a9f000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f29c3899000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f29c3697000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f29c3480000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f29c327b000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f29c3078000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f29c2e75000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f29c2c6f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f29c2a50000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f29c284e000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f29c2648000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f29c243a000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f29c21fe000)
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0x00007f29c1fe6000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f29c1cde000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f29c1a8d000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f29c1885000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f29c1669000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f29c1459000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f29c124f000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f29c0ff0000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f29c0c15000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f29c094a000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f29c0746000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f29c0500000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f29c02af000)
    libhdf5_hl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so.7 (0x00007f29c007f000)
    libhdf5.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so.7 (0x00007f29bfbe3000)
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007f29bf981000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f29bf75f000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f29bf551000)
    librtmp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0 (0x00007f29bf337000)
    libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0x00007f29bf079000)
    libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007f29bed3b000)
    libx264.so.142 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.142 (0x00007f29be9a5000)
    libvpx.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.1 (0x00007f29be5c6000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f29be0f7000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f29bdeca000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007f29bdc8a000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007f29bda71000)
    libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f29bd858000)
    libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f29bd594000)
    libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007f29bd34c000)
    libopenjpeg.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.2 (0x00007f29bd12a000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f29bce9d000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f29bcc8f000)
    libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x00007f29bca78000)
    libcgmanager.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0 (0x00007f29bc85d000)
    libnih.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1 (0x00007f29bc645000)
    libnih-dbus.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1 (0x00007f29bc43b000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f29bc1f6000)
    libVPIC.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libVPIC.so.5.8 (0x00007f29bbfcd000)
    libCosmo.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libCosmo.so.5.8 (0x00007f29bbd9e000)
    libmpi_cxx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1 (0x00007f29bbb84000)
    libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007f29bb803000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f29bb49d000)
    libvtkalglib.so.5.8 => /usr/lib/libvtkalglib.so.5.8 (0x00007f29bb279000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f29bb075000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f29bae6f000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f29bac31000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f29baa29000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f29ba824000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f29ba5f5000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f29ba3ea000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f29ba1e6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f29b9fcb000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f29b9dbc000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f29b9ba1000)
    libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f29b9963000)
    libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00007f29b96e3000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f29b94b0000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f29b929c000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f29b905a000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f29b8e51000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f29b8bcf000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f29b89cc000)
    libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007f29b878c000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f29b8582000)
    libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f29b8379000)
    libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f29b80f1000)
    libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f29b7e50000)
    libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f29b7c1d000)
    libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f29b7a08000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f29b7803000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f29b75f8000)
    libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f29b73cf000)
    libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f29b71c1000)
    libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f29b6f78000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f29b6d3f000)
```

Now when I try to import this library in ipython I get following error:

```
In [1]: import libpcltest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-93c311da18da> in <module>()
----> 1 import libpcltest

ImportError: ./libpcltest.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
```

By simply copy pasting this error in Google, I figured out that this error corresponds to the linking error of the libboost_python.so library.
To confirm my doubt,I checked the ldd output of my library libpcltest.so and realized that link to libboost_python.so is indeed missing.

To investigate further, I then compiled hello.cpp code from the first example using the configuration of the second CMakeLists.txt (which also includes PCL include dirs and links to PCL libraries) and surprisingly the ldd output of resulting shared library does not have link to libboost_python.so

It seems that the error has somethig to do with using libboost_python and PCL together, but I am still clueless how to solve it.

Could someone please help me to figure out the problem here. 
P.S. I am working on ubuntu 14.04 and all the libraries being used here are default system libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what is going wrong here. When I checked the output of `cmake` I get following:

```
badami@Zusi:~/Codes/indor_seg/pySegment/libC++/build$ cmake ..
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
--   chrono
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/badami/Codes/indor_seg/pySegment/libC++/build
```

Here as you can see it finds the Boost libraries twice, once from the system's default boost installation and once from the boost in PCL.

Since in my CMakeLists.txt, I first search for boost libraries and then for PCL, the finding of python library of boost is overwritten by the finding of boost libraries in PCL.

When I change my order in CMakeLists.txt file

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS python)
FIND_PACKAGE(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization features)
```

to

```
FIND_PACKAGE(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization features)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS python)
```

The corresponding output of `cmake` changes to :

```
badami@Zusi:~/Codes/indor_seg/pySegment/libC++/build$ cmake ..
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
--   chrono
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/badami/Codes/indor_seg/pySegment/libC++/build
```

And the libboost_python.so links successfully to the generated shared library.

The more elegant solution is more than welcome.

Comment: Did the trick for me as well. Don't think I would've figured this out on my own, thank you for sharing!